# hg reverse diff of a single revision

Tags: mercurial

If doing `hg diff --rev 1 --rev 2`, one can get the reverse diff by swapping the order of the `--rev` arguments. Is there a way to do this more generally, including when using the `-c` argument, or when taking the diff of the working directory?

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the man page of `hg diff`:

```
--reverse             produce a diff that undoes the changes
```

So simply employ that flag in addition to whatever flags you need to create the diff you are interested in